# Script for running .wav files in the background of Psychopy?

Tags: python, audio, psychopy

Does anyone have a script for running .wav files in the background of Psychopy? I need to deliver pulses of sound while there is a steady .wav file being played.

Comment: Have you tried it? In PsychoPy you simply start one sound playing (e.g. a .wav file) and can then make other beeps occur at any time afterwards. The two sound outputs overlap. You just need a separate sound object for each.